# Как добавить к слайдеру Bootstrap 4 кнопки для переключения?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Вопрос заключается в следующем: я убираю индикаторы в слайдер, делаю слайдер статичным. И нужно, чтобы переключение слайдера осуществлялось либо стрелками, либо вверху над слайдером должны быть кнопки и переключать ими. Как реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если есть конечно уже данная реализация, через другой слайдер, пойдет и так.

Comment: добавьте ваш [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Можно индикаторы просто вынести туда куда надо и  использовать их вместо кнопок. Пример на boostrap 4.

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css";

#carouselExampleIndicators {
  width: 400px;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: relative;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: red;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: null
})
</script>


<!--Индикаторы-->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</li>
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2">3</li>
</ol>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/57d750dc-6893-4a08-93c7-bcb2c0aec8b0/s800" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://1079638729.rsc.cdn77.org/pic/v2/gallery/preview/belki-zhivotnye-33658.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/34158/b4138e2d-0ebb-4c7c-9afc-5b20f705bab1/s800" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Думал как вариант. Но не лучший. Все-таки нужно попробовать по условию.